# WebSite Design - Adding Shapes to a Board

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have run into a small problem on a project I am working on.

Basically I have a page on a website where a single image is displayed. Users can then add shapes over this image.

Sort of like having a board with sticky notes.

The way I was tackling this was by having an invisible grid overlaying the board so that any shape added will be placed inside a cell, but this is giving me issues as the shapes can sometimes be larger than the cell on the grid.

Are there any other libraries I could use which could give me the functionality of adding shapes over an image, with the possibility of saving that shapes position?

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like either your css is wrong or you are adding the overlay in the wrong place =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey this may help you achieve what you want http://fabricjs.com/ its a simple
Javascript HTML5 canvas library that allows images to be loaded over backgrounds

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this will help out alot!